# Different user paths

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

I am implementing a web application, where there is a few different roles which known as systemadmin and employees. System admin will be redirected to path starting as "/admin/xxx" while normal employees will be redirected to "/employees/xxx" after login.

How do I ensure that after login as a system admin, I would not be able to access to employees path when I entered "/employees/xx" manually and vice versa?

```
const antIcon = (
  <LoadingOutlined style={{ fontSize: 100, textAlign: "center" }} spin />
);

toast.configure();

function AuthenticatedRoute({ component: C, appProps, propss, user, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        if (!appProps.isAuthenticated) {
          if (propss.loading) {
            // console.log(typeof user);
            if (localStorage.length === 0) {
              toast.error("You have no authorization to access!");
              return <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login" }} />;
            } else {
              console.log("error");
            }
          }
        }
        if (propss.loading) {
          return (
            <div style={{ textAlign: "center", marginTop: "250px" }}>
              <Spin indicator={antIcon} />
            </div>
          );
        }

        if (appProps.isAuthenticated) {
          return <C {...props} {...appProps} />;
        }
      }}
    />
  );
}
export default AuthenticatedRoute;
```

---

```
    <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/:path?" exact>
          <LoginContainer>
            <Route exact path="/" component={() => <Redirect to="/login" />} />
            <Route
              path="/login"
              render={(props) => {
                if (loading) {
                  return (
                    <div style={{ textAlign: "center", marginTop: "250px" }}>
                      <Spin indicator={antIcon} />
                    </div>
                  );
                } else if (!isAuthenticated) {
                  return <Login {...props} setAuth={setAuth} />;
                } else {
                  if (localStorage.getItem("designation") === "System Admin") {
                    return (
                      <Redirect
                        to="/admin/Dashboard"
                        {...props}
                        setAuth={setAuth}
                      />
                    );
                  } else {
                    return (
                      <Redirect
                        to="/employee/Dashboard"
                        {...props}
                        setAuth={setAuth}
                      />
                    );
                  }
                }
              }}
            />
            <Route path="/forgot" component={ForgotPassword} />
            <Route path="/notFound" component={NotFound} />
          </LoginContainer>
        </Route>

        <UserContext.Provider value={{ user }}>
          <SiderProvider>
            <AuthenticatedRoute path="/admin/:path?">
              <SystemAdminContainer>
                <Switch>
                  
                  <AuthenticatedRoute
                    path="/admin/Dashboard"
                    appProps={{ isAuthenticated }}
                    propss={{ loading }}
                    component={Dashboard}
                    user={user}
                  />
</Switch>
              </SystemAdminContainer>
            </AuthenticatedRoute>

            <AuthenticatedRoute path="/employee/:path?">
              <EmployeeContainer>
                <Switch>
                  <AuthenticatedRoute
                    path="/employee/Dashboard"
                    appProps={{ isAuthenticated }}
                    propss={{ loading }}
                    component={Dashboard}
                    user={user}
                  />
                </Switch>
              </EmployeeContainer>
            </AuthenticatedRoute>
          </SiderProvider>
        </UserContext.Provider>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```

Comment: Why was this question closed?

Comment: I wasn't sure about this too!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, type:string  ,...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    fakeAuth.type === type
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to='/' />
  )} />
)
```

then use it this way

```
<Route path="/login" component={Login} />
<PrivateRoute type={'employe'} path='/employees' component={Employees} />
<PrivateRoute type={'admin'}  path='/admin' component={Admin} />
```

Comment: how to also ensure that the employee will not be able to access to "/admin/xxx"?

Comment: @student404 See my answer
I have edited this that PrivateRoute can be reused for any use

Comment: What to place inside this component={Employees} ?

Comment: @student404 your Employees component

Comment: but i do have another component named AuthenticatedRoute that make sure employee and system admin enter into the correct view of UI

Comment: I've updated with the code i have currently! Pls do take a look at it and enlighten me! :)

Comment: @student404 I'll try to help you, give me my points :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223812/discussion-between-student404-and-yoel).